# nmap in vimrc is working in wrong way

Tags: vimrc

I was trying map a function to key "0".
This is the code I used in vimrc

```
nmap 0 :exec "nohlsearch"<CR>
```

This mapping will allow me to non highlight the word under search

But then I faced problem while trying to move back to start of the line using "0".
0 is mainly used for moving to start of a line. So it was a bad idea and I changed the nmap expression as follows

```
nmap <=> :exec "nohlsearch"<CR>
```

The current expression is working with =. But the issue is whenever I press 0 its, executing "nohlsearch" as before. It's as if the expression is not removed from my vimrc

I searched whether there was any temp file for vimrc. But I couldn't find any. How can I solve this situation

Comment: you need of course to undo the map: `nunmap 0`. Also, you do not need `exec`, just using `:nohlsearch<cr>` is fine

Comment: Christian is probably right: did you restart vim or only `:source $MYVIMRC`?

Comment: Sure @ChristianBrabandt. 
nunmap 0, Is this a vim cmdline I should execute in commandmode?

Comment: `:source $MYVIMRC`

I will try this one @D.BenKnoble

Comment: You’ll have to restart vim or unmap it manually. Deleting a line that creates a mapping doesn’t make it go away

Comment: @D.BenKnoble
I am seeing this error message while I tried to run `source $MYVIMRC` `MYVIMRC: Undefined variable.`

Comment: Bizarre; at any rate, I’m recommending not to do that in this case. Just close vim and re-open it

Comment: Yeah it's cool now.
But I am unable to use = for nohlsearch
This is the mapping I made. 
'nmap <=> : "nohlsearch"<CR>'